# Inconsistent Volume Data from Gdax API

Tags: exchanges, api, coinbase.com, historical-trade-data, gdax

I've queried Gdax API in the past and it seems that the API is currently returning a completely different data set for 'Volume'.

For example, when I queried the API for historical BTC prices around 1 year ago I got the following result set:

> Epoch      |    Low       |   High      |   Open      |  Close      |  Volume
>
> 1517356860    9946.58 9998.42 9990.11 9946.59 2.66059942
>
> 1517356920    9927    9954.9  9935    9940.62 4.23884531
>
> 1517356980    9904.11 9940.63 9940.63 9909.12 2.19973319
>
> 1517357040    9909.12 9947.26 9909.2  9947.25 5.91939066
>
> 1517357100    9947.26 9995    9947.26 9989.98 5.56216334
>
> 1517357160    9909.12 9990.56 9990.56 9909.13 8.78513173
>
> 1517357220    9909.12 9948.97 9909.13 9946.1  5.03904978
>
> 1517357280    9946.1  9962.83 9946.11 9950.22 3.86148175
>
> 1517357340    9918.5  9950.22 9950.21 9918.51 5.53564686
>
> 1517357400    9918.51 9934.21 9918.51 9927.12 0.98890742

However, when I query API for same time frame I now get the following data set:

> 1517356860,9946.58,9998.42,9990.11,9946.59,12.75530468
>
> 1517356920,9927,9954.9,9946.58,9940.62,15.2790945
>
> 1517356980,9904.11,9940.63,9940.63,9909.12,15.94836064
>
> 1517357040,9909.12,9947.26,9909.13,9947.25,24.33637294
>
> 1517357100,9947.26,9995,9947.26,9989.98,21.57384641
>
> 1517357160,9909.12,9990.56,9989.99,9909.13,18.36038141
>
> 1517357220,9909.12,9948.97,9909.13,9946.1,15.38557231
>
> 1517357280,9946.1,9962.83,9946.11,9950.22,5.47653084
>
> 1517357340,9918.5,9950.22,9950.21,9918.51,11.45337408
>
> 1517357400,9918.51,9949,9918.51,9927.12,9.57149122

As you can see the 'volume' (last column) almost never matches previous data set while other columns match most of the time but not always.

What is the explanation for the discrepancy observed and which data should be relied on?

Thanks